# NuGet: Specific Versions in transient Resolve -> Binding Redirects

Tags: nuget

I am using the new nuget mechanism with PackageReferences in the csproj file.
When using the transient resolve no BindingRedirections will be created in the app.config.

For Example:

I installed System.Reactive 3.1.1 with the new nuget format in csproj.
Nuget creates no Binding redirects.
I tried Add-BindingRedirect in the PackageManagerConsole but nothing happens.

When I use the old format (packages.config) nuget creates the following Binding Redirect

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reactive.Core" publicKeyToken="94bc3704cddfc263" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.3000.0" newVersion="3.0.3000.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

The next question is: Why only 1 redirect? System.Reactive depends on multiple nugets but there is only a redirect for one of them?

Can someone please explain this to me?
Thanks in advance

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that the binding redirects are not added to the source `App.config` but are generated by during the build, so your resulting `Foo.exe.config` should have the necessary binding redirects depending on the dependency closure.

This is controlled by a property that is typically set automatically for projects using `PackageReference`:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at the generated config file